# Laravel php tinker command to show tables and structures?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What is he command within Laravels' php artisan tinker that shows tables and/or structure of those tables?

Comment: There isn't one. You would have to figure out the statement to use for your database to retrieve this information.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, SQLite... etc

Answer (score 31):

To get all tables, use this:
`$tables = \DB::select('show tables');`.

To get all columns of table, use this:
`$columns = \Schema::getColumnListing('<table_name>');`

Answer (score 6):

For sqlite, use:

```
DB::select('SELECT NAME FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table"');
```

Answer (score 3):

From the command line you can enter:

```
Schema::getColumnListing('your_table_name_here');
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was

```
$flights = Flight::all();
```

that finally gave me the data from my table https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-models

Answer (score 0):

Use this from Tinker

```
DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('clients');
```